# Why i get null in controller when call in ajax asp.net mvc?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I want to call controller with `ajax` in `asp.net mvc` for that purpose write this code in view page:

```
$("#dbbutton").click(function (e) {

            //Save DB NAME
            var serviceURL = '/DDRS/SaveDBName';
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: serviceURL,
                data: JSON.stringify({ value:$("#DBName").val() }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: successFunc,
                error: errorFunc
            });
            function successFunc(data, status) {
                alert(data);
            }
            function errorFunc() {
                alert('error');
            }
```

and this is my action method in `DDRS` controller:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SaveDBName(string DataBaseName)
        {
            string test = DataBaseName.Trim();
            string sep = test.Substring(0, test.IndexOf(","));

            return Json(test, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

but i get null error in `SaveDBName` in this line:

```
string test = DataBaseName.Trim();
```

What happen?How can i solve that problem?thanks.

Comment: change the below line as  data: { DataBaseName:$("#DBName").val() }, in your ajax call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this issue because you are not sending the data in the format in which ASP.Net MVC expect. ASP.Net MVC need some special format when dealing value like `string` and value type (int, bool etc) parameter when they're used directly as parameter with POST method.

Your controller use a primtiive type but you are sending just

```
data: JSON.stringify({ value:$("#DBName").val() })
```

`value` is not the name of your parameter then it will not bind it to your `DataBaseName` parameter. Even if you replace `value` with the correct parameter name it will not work.

To make it work you must use the below code as data in your jQuery ajax request:

```
data: { "": $("#DBName").val() }
```

Notice that the property name is empty that will tell jQuery to send the data in this format

```
='MyDatabaseNameWillGoHere'
```

With that format, ASP.Net MVC can bind it to your parameter correctly.

To prevent that issue always use a ViewModel.

Comment: `data: JSON.stringify({ DataBaseName: $("#DBName").val() }),` will work just fine :)